# Windows Live Tile of a pinned website not updating

Tags: windows-10, live-tile

Currently I´m trying to implement a windows live tile for my website (http://traunviertler-traunwalchen.de). I created it on http://buildmypinnedsite.com/en and works so far.
Now i tried to change the backgroundcolor, but my pinned website in my start menu is not updating. I tried repinning, clearing serveral caches and temp files with CCleaner, Disk Cleanup and manually.
So how can i force Edge refreshing his cache according to the browserconfig.xml of my website? I´ve got this issue on Windows10-Desktop and Windows10-mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these steps:

1. Turn live tiles off
2. Unpin tile
3. MS Edge browser cache and history clearing
4. Delete all content within C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local/Packages/Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_randomized_hash/LocalState/PinnedTiles
   .
5. Delete file iconcache.db inside C:/Users/user_name/AppData/Local
6. Disk Cleanup

Comment: You're lucky. But it doesn't work in my case unfortunately :( I've changed xml path but windows still requests old uri-s...

Answer (score 0):

Sadly force updating live tiles isn't an option in windows 10 yet.

Removing the tile, then visiting the site and then readding the tile might fix the problem temporarily, but until Microsoft comes up with a proper fix, you will just have to wait.

Comment: The problem is: Readding does NOT change the tile. Follwing scenario: I add the tile (red background), then i unpin it and change the source to make the tile have a green background. I upload it and remove temp files. And now when i pin it again. It still has red background; not a green one.